# how do i extract info from a file in vbscript

Tags: string, vbscript, size, extract, doc

lets take an example. i have a folder having 20 files. lets assume that all files are over 1 mb.. my objective is to copy first 500 kb (ie the string which occupies first 500kb) and write it to another file. then loop it and do the same for each of the 20 files. the writing of files must happen in 20 individual files.

for example i have

```
               1.doc1.txt
               2.doc2.txt
               3.doc.exe
               4.doc.jpg
               so on
```

i want

```
             first 500kb of doc1.txt to be saved in dup1.txt,
             first 500kb of doc2.txt in dup2.txt and so on.
```

is it possible to do this using vbscript? if yes how??? looks really complex to me.. .. please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [`ADODB.Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677486) object for this:

```
Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type = 1  'binary
stream.LoadFromFile "doc1.txt"
chunk = stream.Read(512000)
stream.Close

stream.Open
stream.Type = 1  'binary
stream.Write chunk
stream.SaveToFile "dup1.txt", 2
stream.Close
```

An input file can be split into several chunks using 2 `Stream` objects like this:

```
Set iStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

iStream.Open
iStream.Type = 1  'binary
iStream.LoadFromFile "doc1.txt"

oStream.Open
oStream.Type = 1  'binary
oStream.Write iStream.Read(512000)
oStream.SaveToFile "dup.txt", 2
oStream.Close

oStream.Open
oStream.Type = 1  'binary
oStream.Write iStream.Read(512000)
oStream.SaveToFile "dup1.txt", 2
oStream.Close

oStream.Open
oStream.Type = 1  'binary
oStream.Write iStream.Read(512000)
oStream.SaveToFile "dup2.txt", 2
oStream.Close

...

iStream.Close
```

This can be simplified by wrapping repeating code segments in a procedure or function:

```
Const chunksize = 512000

Sub WriteChunk(data, filename)
  Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  oStream.Open
  oStream.Type = 1  'binary
  oStream.Write data
  oStream.SaveToFile filename, 2
  oStream.Close
End Sub

Set iStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

iStream.Open
iStream.Type = 1  'binary
iStream.LoadFromFile "doc1.txt"

WriteChunk iStream.Read(chunksize), "dup.txt"
WriteChunk iStream.Read(chunksize), "dup1.txt"
WriteChunk iStream.Read(chunksize), "dup2.txt"
...

iStream.Close
```

Comment: thank you man! you are an encyclopedia of vbscript! i will try this and get back to you. thanks again!

Comment: your program works!!! as always. wanna now learn to loop such that chunks of the same file is stored in different files one after the other... for example: 500kb in dup.txt..nxt 500 in dup1,next in dup2 till the end of the file

Comment: sorry..didnt know this feature.. i have accepted all the answers which i have accepted to my questions so far..  :)

Comment: thank you bro! i am really learning a lot. wouldnt be possible without you

Comment: That is an entirely different question. New questions should be asked as new questions. I have rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhyx75w2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method of a read-opened [TextStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/312a5kbt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to read the chunk from your input file and the [.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ee7s9w2%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method of a write-open TextStream to write it to your output file.

Sample code:

```
>> Dim tsIn : Set tsIn = goFS.OpenTextFile("00.vbs")
>> Dim tsOut : Set tsOut = goFS.CreateTextFile("00.head")
>> tsOut.Write tsIn.Read(10)
>> tsIn.Close
>> tsOut.Close
>> WScript.Echo goFS.OpenTextFile("00.head").ReadAll()
>>
Option Exp
```

Comment: wats goFS? i mean instance of which object?

Comment: the program you have written copies strings on the basis of number of characters bro. i wanted a program which reads string on the basis of its size. but i learnt something new :) thank you